# Cómo cambiar la opción seleccionada html usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un menú de opciones de esta manera:

```
<form action="feeding" method="post">
    <select id="feedingHay">
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
       <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>

  <strong class="section-fourrage section-fourrage-target">3</strong>
</form>
```

Como le puedo hacer para que seleccione automáticamente el valor 3 de la entrada "feedingHay" a base del numero 3 de la entrada "strong"?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, quieres hacer con JS que tu `select` seleccione lo que tiene dentro tu etiqueta `strong`??

Comment: Si, es posible hacer eso?

Comment: Lo que hay dentro de la etiqueta strong viene de una variable??

Comment: Si es posible, pero pues no tiene mucha utilidad.

Comment: No viene de una variable

Comment: Pues solo tienes que ponerle selected a la etiqueta option con value=3, aunque no le veo la finalidad

Comment: Yo no puedo hacer ninguna edición html a la página, estoy utilizando una aplicación llamada Tampermonkey para crear un Script y seleccionar automáticamente ese valor mediante el numero de la entrada `Strong`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con Jquery puedes hacer ésto :

```
$('#feedingHay').val($('#songValue').outerText);
```

si le pones al Strong un

> id = songValue

y como dicen los comentarios, no tiene mucho sentido lo que quieres hacer

**EDIT: Usando Javascript puro**

```
document.getElementById("feedingHay").value = document.getElementById("songValue").outerText
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me sirvio!

Comment: Imagino habrás usado el class del Strong, si no puedes hacer ediciones html

Answer (score 1):

Sería así:

```
  document.getElementById("feedingHay").options.item(2).selected = 'selected';
```

Recuerda que este código javascript debes ponerlo después de que se cargue la página o no funcionará.

Comment: @Javi Puede ser confuso pero estoy en lo cierto, la etiqueta para seleccionar una `option` en HTML es selected='selected', no está mal.

Comment: disculpas Erlantz, estabas en lo cierto, me confundí con otra cosa ;-p disculpas

Comment: me confundía con checked.... ajajajaa

Comment: @Javi ningún problema, es confuso jajajaja

Comment: pero no obstante, tienes razón que se puede hacer como dices, pero desde JS la manera correcta sería escribiendo = true o false, ya que en tu caso como harías para quitar la selección? Es cierto que desde el elemento HTML se dede indicar solamente selected, pero si queremos realizar un cambio en el estado de selected de ese elemento desde Java script la manera correcta es indicando true o false. :)

Comment: @Javi Puede ser, me lo apunto.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ponerle un id a tu etiqueta `strong` y despues con JS tomar lo que tiene dentro y darselo a tu select para que lo muestre.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var seleccion = document.getElementById("seleccion");
  var select = document.getElementById("feedingHay");
  select.value = seleccion.innerHTML;
};
```

```html
<form action="feeding" method="post">
    <select id="feedingHay">
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
       <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>

  <strong id="seleccion" class="section-fourrage section-fourrage-target">3</strong>
</form>
```